# URL for first number page in codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

How can put url for link number `1` like other links, in codeigniter pagination, when start(refresh) page

> « First < **1** 2 3 4 5 > Last »

by default number `1` is `<strong>1</strong>`. i want it same like other number get link page in first load page.

How is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the config for pagination.
From the docs ( http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html ):

```
//Customizing the "Current Page" Link

$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a href="'.base_url().$this->uri->uri_string().'">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
```

You can change the values of these to `<span>` or whatever else you choose.

Comment: I don't want change this tag, i want put link(tag a, like: `<a href="http://localhost/index/5">2</a>`) for this, how is it?

Comment: OK, what you're saying is that when the page is on page "1", that you want that number "1" to be a link instead of the default `<strong>1</strong>`. That is precisely what the `$config['cur_tag_open']` and `$config['cur_tag_close']` does. By default, the library sets it up with the strong, but it gives you the flexibility to change it. I'll update my answer to show you how to make the current page link to the, well, "current" page.

Comment: Ok, i put your code in myself code and get error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function uri_string() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\application\libraries\Zigvp.php on line 47` . how fix it?

Comment: OK, so you're using this in a library (might have been helpful to know that). You need the CI instance. Somewhere in your library, you should have some code like this: `$CI =& get_instance();` - where "$CI" is the variable that the instance is being assigned to. replace `$this` in my code to whatever that variable is: something like `$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a href="'.base_url().$CI->uri->uri_string().'">';` -- depending if that variable is a class variable or a local variable in a method.

Comment: If it's a class variable (meaning that it is declared **outside** of any methods in the library), then you would use `$this->CI->uri->uri_string()`.

Answer (score 0):

Wow this is an amazingly difficult question to read - But I think the general idea is you want to customize the look / functionality of your CI pagination.

Since I barely understand what you're asking, here is the obvious thing to do:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

That link goes over the pagination class clearly.

I may be able to clarify more if you clean up the question a bit.

Comment: I would guess that the questioner's first language isn't English. You probably don't need to be so rude about it.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter allows you to customize the First Link .

You can change the opening and closing tags of the First Link .

```
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<div>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</div>';
```

So just find out what the other links use by default and use them as your opening and closing tags ..

Comment: I don't want change this tag, i want put link(tag a, like: `<a href="http://localhost/index/5">2</a>`) for this, how is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $config['cur_tag_open']='<li><a href="[removed]void(0);" class="page_active">';
    $config['cur_tag_close']='</a></li>';
```