# Codeigniter First Link (<) not displaying and Last Link not returning any value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am not getting the First Link like `<`, But i am getting the Last Link like `>` But it does not gives any value (Returning just the base url value)

I referred [URL for first number page in codeigniter pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842689/url-for-first-number-page-in-codeigniter-pagination)

But my problem is not solved

### Edit :

This is my url :

```
http://mydomain.com/ci/index.php/site/blogs/4
```

Here is the screen

[image]

Here is my Code. What is the mistake i am

**Here is the Controller :**

```
$this->load->library("pagination");
$this->load->model("mainmodel");
$config = array();
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a href="'.base_url().$this->menu_blog.'">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '<a href="'.base_url().$this->menu_blog.'">';
$config["base_url"] = base_url().$this->menu_blog;
$config["total_rows"] = $this->mainmodel->record_count();
$config["per_page"] = 2;
$config["uri_segment"] = 1;
$choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
$config["num_links"] = round($choice);
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$data["results"] = $this->mainmodel->fetch_blog($config["per_page"], $page);
$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$menu['menu']="blog";
$menu['title']="Home Page";
$data['query_getall'] = $this->mainmodel->getall('blog');
$data['query_getall1'] = $this->mainmodel->getall('blog_tag');
$this->loader('site/blog/index',$menu,$data);
```

**Here is the model :**

```
public function record_count() 
{
return $this->db->count_all("blog");
}
public function fetch_blog($limit, $start) {
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
$query = $this->db->get("blog");
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
$data[] = $row;
}
return $data;
}
return false;
}
```

Here is the View :

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $data) 
{
    $blogid=$data->link;
?>
<?php print $data->title; ?> 
<?php
}
?>
<p><?php echo $links; ?></p>
```

Comment: you need to use first uri segment ? $config["uri_segment"] = 1;

Comment: Yes i used it and it was in my code.. You want it to use it at top or what ?

Comment: could you please put this line before $config["uri_segment"] = 1;

Comment: $page = ($this->uri->segment(3, 0))? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

Comment: while i post the $config["uri_segment"] = 1; after the $page = ($this->uri->segment(3, 0))? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0; The Before Link Button **<** appears but the **>** disappears

Answer (score 1):

this problem is caused by uri segment default value of codeigniter.codeigniter usually get the 3th segment.

so you need to some change:

```
  $page = $this->uri->segment(1, 0);     // override the default of codeigniter
```

Comment: Should i have the $page = $this->uri->segment(1, 0);  after the $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0; ?

Comment: $page = $this->uri->segment(1, 0); 
 $config["uri_segment"] = 1;

Comment: Same problem exists :( . The end **>** is returning the value of 1